# Numpy calculate product of differences of two matrices against all rows in matrix

Tags: numpy

the following is what I want to achieve. Is there a way to do this efficiently with Numpy or other methods in Python? Since my data would be big. I would like to do it more efficiently. Thank you in advance.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(6).reshape(3,2)
y = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))

for i in range(len(z)):
    for j in range(len(z[0])):
        z[i,j] = np.prod(x[i] - y[j])
```

Comment: If np.prod is np.sum, then life would be easier. I can just use cdist in scipy package. Unfortunately this is not the case. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just vectorize your code:

```
z = (x[:,None]-y).prod(axis=-1)
```

Output:

```
array([[ 0,  4, 16, 36, 64],
       [ 4,  0,  4, 16, 36],
       [16,  4,  0,  4, 16]])
```

Intermediate:

```
(x[:,None]-y).

array([[[ 0,  0],
        [-2, -2],
        [-4, -4],
        [-6, -6],
        [-8, -8]],

       [[ 2,  2],
        [ 0,  0],
        [-2, -2],
        [-4, -4],
        [-6, -6]],

       [[ 4,  4],
        [ 2,  2],
        [ 0,  0],
        [-2, -2],
        [-4, -4]]])
```

Comment: you are a lifesaver. Thanks so much for getting back to me so quickly!!!

Comment: May I ask how did y expand its dimension in this case?

Comment: You have `(3, 2)` and `(5, 2)` as input. For each of the rows in `x` you want to compare to all values of `y`. Thus converting `x` to `(3, 1, 2)` enables to have a `(3, 5, 2)` intermediate. Does it make sense?

Comment: Or phrased otherwise, from `(3, 2)` and `(5, 2)` you want to broadcast `3` and `5`, so put them in a different dimension.